# soapfault: Couldn't create SOAP message

Tags: android, web-services, soapfault

```
11-23 16:19:30.085: SoapFault - faultcode: 'S:Client' faultstring: 'Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
11-23 16:19:30.085: at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.parseBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:121)
11-23 16:19:30.085: at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:137)
11-23 16:19:30.085: at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
11-23 16:19:30.085: at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:104)
11-23 16:19:30.085: at com.mobilebox.webservice.CommonWSClient.callWS(CommonWSClient.java:247)
11-23 16:19:30.085: at com.mobilebox.webservice.CommonWSClient.access$1(CommonWSClient.java:217)
11-23 16:19:30.085: at com.mobilebox.webservice.CommonWSClient$WSHandle.run(CommonWSClient.java:201)
11-23 16:19:30.085: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-23 16:19:30.085: at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-23 16:19:30.085: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

My Android application use `Soap` webservice client to call remote method. Sometimes, it will return the excepion as above. When I call it with `SoapUI`, it never occours.

Comment: Can you paste some code here? So we can able to help you in problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have found out , it's the response error message from the server.
  I will continue to find out why there is such error.

server response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
            <faultcode>S:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Couldn't create SOAP message due to exception: Unable to create StAX reader or writer</faultstring>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```